# Function to generate dropdown notifications Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Inside the dashboardHeader, how can you programatically generate dropdown menu items?

```
dropdownMenu(
  type = "notifications",
  notificationItem(
    text = "message",
    icon = icon("welcome"),
    status = "warning"
  ),
  notificationItem(
    text = "message",
    icon = icon("welcome"),
    status = "warning"
  ),

... #Generate lots more messages
```

What is the general method in R to generate messages, say from another function that takes in an argument which is the number of messages:

```
GenerateMessages <- function(number.of.messages) {
#Code to generate messages
}
```

What would be the code, would it be written in the UI or the Server functions in shiny, dashboard header?

Comment: Here is a basic example of how to create a dropdown menu dynamically. It shold be on the server side of course. http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

Comment: Yeah I read the tutorial and had to generalize it more to fit the output but in the end it is scalable to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since it goes beyond the basic dynamic tutorial. I really like this solution because my notifications and logic can go outside of my code, it shortened my `app.R` by hundreds of lines.

The general form is:

#### Code inside the UI function:

```
# Code to create outputs goes in dashboardHeader 
dropdownMenuOutput("messages.type"),
dropdownMenuOutput("notifications.type"),
dropdownMenuOutput("tasks.type")
```

#### Code inside Server function:

```
# Code to generate headers
output$messages.type <- renderMenu(
  dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = MessageGenerator())
)
output$notifications.type <- renderMenu(
  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", .list = NotificationsGenerator())
)
output$tasks.type <- renderMenu(
  dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", .list = TasksGenerator())
)
```

The main logic is in the `MessageGenerator()` function. These functions generate a list required to render in the output. The data structure is from a data.frame containing the message information with the proper headers.

This solution scales to generate messages of the three types Messages, Tasks, and Notifications using three functions `MessageGenerator()`, `TasksGenerator()`, `NotificationsGenerator()`.